# C# search method

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble coming up with the following search method:

```
public override List<Team> Search(Dictionary<string, string> prms, int pageSize, int page, out int results) 
    {
        var tresults = new List<Team>();
        string temp1 = "";
        string temp2 = "";

        using (SqlConnection conn = DB.GetSqlConnection())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"Search";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in prms)
                {
                   temp1 = pair.Key;
                   temp2 = pair.Value;
                }

                if (temp1 == "TeamName")
                {
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("TeamName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    p1.Value = temp2;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("CityName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    p2.Value = null;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
                }

                else if (temp1 == "CityName")
                {
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("TeamName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    p1.Value = null;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("CityName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    p2.Value = temp2;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
                }

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            }
        }
        //results = 1 + 1;

        throw new NotImplementedException("Must be implemented by class. ");
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is basically what this test is doing:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void SearchForTeam()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        int total = 0;
        dic.Add("TeamName", "Patriots");
        var nd = new TeamRepository();
        var teams = nd.Search(dic, 100, 1, out total);

        Assert.IsTrue(teams.Find(p => p.TeamName == "Patriots") != null);
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is have my method search by either Team Name (SQL column "TeamName", value "Patriots") or by City Name (SQL column "CityName" value "Chicago", etc. I think my issues mainly are that I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding how the dictionary works.
Also, I'm not sure how the value I'm returning should work because I am both returning an int (from the out parameter) and type List. This is all pretty new to me, so its the basics that I don't quite understand I suppose.

Comment: `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in prms) { temp1 = Key; temp2 = pair.Value; }` will set `temp1` and `temp2` to the *last* key/value pair in the dictionary. You probably want the `foreach` to encompass a lot more of your code (like the `if` statements).

Comment: also why an out and a list as return, if you need the count of results the list can tell you

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public override List<Team> Search(Dictionary<string, string> prms, int pageSize, int page) 
{
    var tresults = new List<Team>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = DB.GetSqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"Search";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in prms)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(pair.Key, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = pair.Value });

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            // I assume you'll use pageSize and page here?
        }
    }

    return tresults; // I assume this is what you want to return.
}
```

If you don't want to use a specific column for your search, then there's no need to create a `SqlParameter` for that column and sets its `Value` to `null` -- just don't use that column!

Also, there's no need to have `out int results`. If you're returning the list of teams, then the invoker can just get the team count from the list (`teams.Count`). (If you are doing something else with `results`, then by all means ignore this paragraph.)

Comment: would this not potentially violate the number of params, say I passed in 3 rows all with TeamName as key, the stored procedure would probably not expect 3 params called TeamName?

Comment: @Pharabus Dictionaries have unique keys in C#, so that wouldn't even be possible.

Answer (score 0):

it's kind of hard to see what you are getting at here, I am unsure that you need a dictionary at all (would you pass in multiple records?)

personally I would do the below, the assumption is the stored procedure could handle the possibility of both parameters being populated if both are passed in completed.

```
public override List<Team> Search(string teamName,string cityName, int pageSize, int page) 
    {
        var tresults = new List<Team>();


        using (SqlConnection conn = DB.GetSqlConnection())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"Search";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("TeamName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    p1.Value = teamName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("CityName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    p2.Value = cityName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);


                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    tresults.Add(BuildTeamFromReader(reader));
                }

            }
        }
        return tresults;

    }


    private Team BuildTeamFromReader(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var team = new Team();
        team.TeamName = reader["TeamName"];//or whatever your column name is for team name
//ToDo other mappings
            return team;
        }
```